# 3D rotation in libgdx

Tags: 3d, libgdx, rotation

Here is what I’m trying to do.
I have the box that is *ModelInstance*. First I rotate it for some angle with this.

```
box.transform.rotate(1, 0, 0, angle);
```

That look something like this

[image: image 1]

Next I want to rotate it around world (global) axis (if something like that exists). I have no idea how to do this.
This is what I mean, when I do

```
box.transform.rotate(0, 1, 0, angle);
```

[image: a busy cat]

Can someone explain how to do this. I have been reading about quaternions and transformations in 3D for 2 days now but still i have no idea how to do this.